# ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv1_pad is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, 224, 3]

Tags: keras, tensorflow, image-classification, python-3.x

I am trying to make a gender classifier. I am using MobileNet from Tensorflow with input shape as (224,224,3). After training the model, I tried to check if the model was working by passing an image to the model to predict, but it throws the error in the title. I tried debugging it and google the error and tried everything I could, but the error still persists. Please help me to understand why the error.

```
model = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet.MobileNet(input_shape = (224,224,3), include_top = False, pooling = 'avg')
#model.summary()

x = Dropout(rate=0.4)(model.output)
x = Dense(3)(x)
x = Softmax()(x)
model= Model(model.inputs, x)

for layer in model.layers[:-3]:
    layer.trainable = False

model.compile(
    optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001),
    loss='categorical_crossentropy'
)

datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet.preprocess_input, 
          shear_range = 0.2, zoom_range = 0.2, horizontal_flip = True, validation_split = 0.1)
training = datagen.flow_from_directory( 
    '...\Pictures\Model', 
    target_size=(224, 224)
)

validation = datagen.flow_from_directory( 
    '...\Pictures\Model',
    target_size=(224, 224)
)

batch_size = 32

history = model.fit_generator(generator = training, steps_per_epoch = training.samples//batch_size, epochs = 10, 
                              validation_data = validation, validation_steps = validation.samples//batch_size, verbose = 2)

man = np.array(tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img('...\\Pictures\\Detected Faces\\0156224224_face.jpg', target_size = (224,224)))

model.predict(man) #Here the model throws an error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure to add an extra dimension for the batch size, if you are passing in a single image the batch size would be 1. You can use [`np.expand_dims`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) to add the extra dimension.

Comment: It's working! Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/94071/feature-extraction-with-mobilenet-visualization Hi, could you take a look here?

Answer (score 0):

The error is because the model is expecting input of shape of 4 dimensional data [None, 224, 224, 3] where None is the Batch size which can be anything. but you are giving a single image of shape which is three dimensional.

try model.predict([man]) here we are just changing dimension to 4D with a batch size of 1.

Comment: I tried that but its showing: 
ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv1_pad is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [32, 224, 3]
Idk why the shape has 32 now. I'm passing (224,224,3)

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/94071/feature-extraction-with-mobilenet-visualization Hi, could you take a look here?